# HTML and CSS horizontal adjustment

Tags: html, css, web

I am building a chat functionality in a web page and I'm having trouble with the design of the submit field I have in mind. I will provide you with a picture of my goal, and the code that currently[image] formats them.

And here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="submitField">
    <textarea   class="submitArea" form="usrform"> </textarea>
    <form action="" id="usrform">
    <input type="submit" class="submitBtn">
    </form>
  </div>
```

And the CSS code:

```
.submitField {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: red;
        display: inline-block;
}



.submitArea {
    width: 50vh;
    height: 8vh;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    font-size: 16px;
    resize: none;
    color: black;
        position: relative;
}

.submitBtn {
    color: black;
}
```

I know using classes on everything might be less than optimal, but what else am I doing wrong right now? Tips on what I need to change to get the **New** look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give the button a `position:absolute;` and then give it a `left: 50px;` and a `right: 50px;`

Comment: I need to do a bit more than left 50px; and right: 50px; but you got me on the right track, thanks!

Comment: I know I didnt want to calculate it I just wanted to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.submitField {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
}



#usrform {
    width: 15%;
    display: inline-block;
    align-self: center;
}



.submitBtn {
    color: black;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```